# Nested Count with having Clause mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count images selected from different categories my query below return error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( select count(i1.id) as cnt FROM image_gallery i1 LEFT OUTER JOIN image_g' at line 2

Where I am wrong ?

```
SELECT count(*)
(select count(*)
FROM image_gallery i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN image_gallery i2
  ON (i1.category_id = i2.category_id AND i1.id < i2.id)
GROUP BY i1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 10 
) as total_pics
```

Comment: The `count(*)` outside of the subquery... what table are you querying for that count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `FROM` keyword

```
SELECT sum(cnt)
FROM
(
  select count(i1.id) as cnt
  FROM image_gallery i1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN image_gallery i2 ON i1.category_id = i2.category_id 
                                  AND i1.id < i2.id
  GROUP BY i1.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 10 
) as total_pics
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response Sir, But my query still return error:- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
  select count(i1.id) as cnt
  FROM image_gallery i1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN image_g' at line 2

Comment: Thanks It works Sir, But the return result not match having count(*) less than 10 if I have 4 categories then return sum from from this query must be 40 but it return 184 ? how is it done ?

Comment: Execute the inner query and see if this is what you want or if you need to adjust that.